# Services are delayed starting

Tags: windows-7

I am currently using windows 7 ultimate. The problem I am facing is when I am starting the machine it starts normally . And then some of the crucial services like I can click window logo and the menu pops up but I can't click any of them rather it gives ding-dong sound. I can't type a programme in the search bar. The wifi logo is like it's loading but not working, the rapid storage technology is not started. But after a few minutes (may be 5) everything works fine. After setting rapid storage technology startup type from delayed to automatic the rapid storage is now working as soon as I start the machine, but other services are starting after 5 mins, it looks like some services have been set to delayed startup, but I don't know . now how to set all the essential services back to automatic start-up mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem. It was caused by Intel Rapid Storage Technology driver/tooling. I didn't find a solution different than uninstalling it.

If I'm not mistaken IRST is useful mostly for its "fake RAID" capabilities - if you're not using them, just remove IRST.

Comment: thank you for the reply, the question is if I uninstall IRST would it affect other services in anyway?

Comment: @Sayan No, it shouldn't. But as always - make sure your backups are up to date first. Making a system restore point wouldn't be a bad idea too.